# I can't find the /dev/watchdog

Tags: linux-kernel, devices, watchdog

I need use the watchdog, but I can't find any watchdog device. It means I need softdog?  But I use `modprobe softdog` it still does not work.  So I download the new Kernel 4.10.10.  But I don't know how to find the sofedog modules. Just like this.

So where I can find the softdog modules?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was your previous kernel compiled too? Why are you compiling kernels? Please add to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The software watchdog option is now in `Device Drivers`->`Watchdog Timer Support`->`Software watchdog`

It can be a bit tedious to search for the location of certain options in the `menuconfig` but it actually took me less than a minute to find it.